# parallel make: two targets depend on the same prerequisite, what happens?

Tags: parallel-processing, makefile

I need to build sources to binary file and two a static library.
Here is an example (I replaced recipes with ';' for brevity):

```
objects := a.o b.o ...
.PHONY: all build build_lib
all: build build_lib
build: bin/app
build_lib: bin/libapp.a
bin/app: $(objects) ;
bin/libapp.a $(objects) ;
obj/%.o: %.cpp ;
```

Will there be problems with parallel build? Can two make processes try to rebuild the same *.o file at once, making a broken build?

I guessed that, they can, so I rewritten the code this way:

```
objects := a.o b.o ...
.PHONY: all build build_lib
all: $(objects) | bin/app bin/libapp.a
build: bin/app
build_lib: bin/libapp.a
bin/app: $(objects) ;
bin/libapp.a $(objects) ;
obj/%.o: %.cpp ;
```

But the --debug=b output still shows:

```
Processing target file `all'.
 File `all' does not exist.
  Processing target file `bin/app'.
   File `bin/app' does not exist.
    Processing target file `obj/client.o'.
    Need to rebuild target `obj/client.o'.
...
 File `sb_all' does not exist.
   File `bin/app' does not exist.
   File `bin/libapp.a' does not exist.
 File `sb_all' does not exist.
   File `bin/app' does not exist.
   File `bin/libapp.a' does not exist.
...
  Need to rebuild target `bin/app'.
g++  -lgd ...
  Need to rebuild target `bin/libapp.a'.
ar ...
File `all' does not exist.
Target file `all' rebuilt successfully.
```

So it seems that my $(objects) target does not run before order-only prerequisites, or do I incorrectly read output? And did I need this change anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no problem with it.  Make will not have any problem with parallelism and multiple targets (*in the same instance of make*) depending on the same prerequisite.  If you have recursive instances of make and multiple different make instances try to build the same target you'll have problems.

Order-only doesn't have any impact on parallelism at all.  Make will still invoke things in parallel if possible.  The *only* way to impact the order in which rules are run is to declare a prerequisite relationship between those targets.  Here you're just saying that both the higher-level targets must be built before the `all` target, so that doesn't do anything to reduce parallelism.

Luckily as I said above, you don't have to.  As long as your makefile correctly defines the dependency relationship between any two targets, make will handle the bigger picture just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, MadScientist.